# Space Key Click Event in android

Tags: android, keyevent

I want to get the space key event in an android keyboard.
I tried some codes from google searches. but nothing is working.

```
 public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE){
            Toast.makeText(PrabheshActivity.this, "ssss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

why is this not working? please help

Comment: you can also add a textwatcher in edittext and on every key pressed you will receive a callback there you can check for empty space

Comment: @vikaskumar I have tried that too. but how to check the kay is space or not

Comment: Looks like you're using event.getAction() instead of keycode to check for space key. Try this

if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE)) {
//Handle space key press
}

Comment: @raxerz it's not working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try adding the `TextWatcher` as text input listener and see if you have any spaces received. Check for ASCII code for space i.e 32

For Ex:

```
private TextWatcher postTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    private int lastLength;

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        lastLength = s.length();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        try {
            if (lastLength > s.length()) return;
            if (s.charAt(s.length() - 1) == 32) {
                //32 is ascii code for space, do something when condition is true.
            }
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
            //handle the exception
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        //do something
    }
};
```